# NSURLConnection delegates are not firing when used inside custom complete handler

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

When i use `NSURLConnection` inside a custom complete handler method. The delegate methods are not firing. So what i have to do to make it fire. I want to perform operation when i receive url.

```
[self exportTo:asset withHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error){
                        NSLog(@"URL : %@, error: %@", url, error);

                        NSString *urlString = @"";

                        // setting up the request object now
                        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
                        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


                        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];



                        [request setHTTPBody:body];
                        NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                        if (conn)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // inform the user that the download could not be made
                            // NSLog(@"failed to send");
                        }
                    }];
```

Comment: What thread is the handler called on? Does that thread have a run loop?

Comment: After i User `CFRunLoopRun();` the delegate methods are firing. I found the solution.